# Infinite horizontal collectionView with first cell able to scroll left

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I created an infinite horizontal collectionView presenting the first 6 items of my database, something like carousel. So, when I am scrolling to the right side, I can see those 6 items with the order I got them in that way:

**1**-2-3-4-5-6-1-2-3-4-5-6-1-2... etc.
(bold 1 represents the first cell of collection view)

What I need to do now is when the collection view is rendered and I can see the first item, if I scroll left I want to present the last item I got from database (the 6th item).

...1-2-3-4-5-6-**1**-2-3-4-5-6-1-2-3-4-5-6-1-2... etc.
(again, bold 1 represents the first cell of collection view)

Do you know how I can implement this feature?

Comment: Are your cells fixed-width? or variable width depending on the data?

Comment: @DonMag on every page, I am presenting two cells with fixed width.

Comment: OK - using your question, you have **6** data elements/records? So, in `cellForItemAt` are you doing something like `dataArray[indexPath.item % 6]` to accomplish your carousel effect?

Comment: @DonMag exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various different ways to accomplish this... which method to use would depend on a number of things related to your UI layout.

But, assuming we **do** want to use a horizontal-scrolling collection view, and, based on your comments you want paging with two cells per page...

Let's say we have a simple string array for our data:

```
let myData: [String] = [
    "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6",
]
```

If we have a simple single-label collection view cell, our `cellForItemAt` could look like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: SimpleCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! SimpleCell
    
    let thisData = myData[indexPath.item % myData.count]
    cell.theLabel.text = thisData
    
    return cell
    
}
```

That gives us the "carousel" effect.

To allow the user to scroll right-to-left ***immediately***, we cannot start at `item: 0`.

So, we can set the number of items to some absurdly large number that nobody will ever scroll to, such as:

```
lazy var totalCells: Int = myData.count * 100_000
```

Then (I'm assuming) in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` - where we know the width of the collection view - we're setting the flow layout's `.itemSize` ... ***and*** we can scroll the collection view to `totalCells / 2`.

Might look something like this:

```
var cvWidth: CGFloat = -1.0

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    print(#function)
    if cvWidth != myCollectionView.frame.size.width {
        cvWidth = myCollectionView.frame.size.width
        if let fl = myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            let h = fl.itemSize.height
            let w = (cvWidth - fl.minimumInteritemSpacing) * 0.5
            fl.itemSize = .init(width: w, height: h)
        }
        
        // start with collection view "scrolled half-way"
        //  through the absurdly large number of items
        let startItem: Int = totalCells / 2
        myCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: startItem, section: 0), at: .left, animated: false)
        
        // enable paging here
        myCollectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Now when the user first sees the collection view, it will already be scrolled to item `300_000`, and we can scroll both left and right.

Here's a quick, complete example...

**simple single-label cell**

```
class SimpleCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    static let identifier: String = "simpleCell"
    
    public var theLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .bold)
        label.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        label.textColor = .white
        label.textAlignment = .center
        return label
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        
        theLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(theLabel)
        
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            theLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            theLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        ])
        
        // so we can see the cell framing
        contentView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        
    }
}
```

**example view controller with collection view**

```
class SimpleExampleVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    let myData: [String] = [
        "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6",
    ]
    
    // some absurdly large number that nobody will ever scroll to
    lazy var totalCells: Int = myData.count * 100_000
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let fl = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        fl.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        fl.minimumLineSpacing = 0.0
        fl.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0
        
        // .itemSize width will be changed in viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        fl.itemSize = .init(width: 120.0, height: 60.0)
        
        myCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: fl)
        
        myCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(myCollectionView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            myCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            myCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            myCollectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            myCollectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 64.0),
        ])
        
        myCollectionView.register(SimpleCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: SimpleCell.identifier)
        myCollectionView.dataSource = self
        myCollectionView.delegate = self

        // paging should be disabled at this point
        //  we don't have to worry if we're creating the collection view
        //  via code, as we're doing here... but...
        //  if we're using Storyboard, we want to make sure
        //  paging is NOT set to true
        myCollectionView.isPagingEnabled = false

        // just so we can see the framing
        myCollectionView.backgroundColor = .darkGray
    }
    
    var cvWidth: CGFloat = -1.0
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        print(#function)
        if cvWidth != myCollectionView.frame.size.width {
            cvWidth = myCollectionView.frame.size.width
            if let fl = myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
                let h = fl.itemSize.height
                let w = cvWidth * 0.5
                fl.itemSize = .init(width: w, height: h)
            }
            
            // start with collection view "scrolled half-way"
            //  through the absurdly large number of items
            let startItem: Int = totalCells / 2
            myCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: startItem, section: 0), at: .left, animated: false)
            
            // enable paging here
            myCollectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
        }
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return totalCells
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: SimpleCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! SimpleCell
        
        let thisData = myData[indexPath.item % myData.count]
        cell.theLabel.text = thisData
        
        return cell
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the explanation! I have another question related to the variable 'myCollectionView' you are using. I am working with Storyboard and the collectionView I have is embedded to a tableView cell. Do you know how to access the collectionView in order to use it to the 'viewDidLayoutSubviews' function ?

Comment: @LouizaA - you cannot do that in the controller's `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. In your table view cell class, implement `override func layoutSubviews() { }` -- assuming you've setup your embedded collection view constraints properly, at that point you can get the width of the collection view frame.

Comment: Can you update your answer to provide an example with paging with one cell per page? Apart from a collectionView with paging with two cells per page I have to create a new collectionView with one cell per page and it's difficult to make it work... Basically, I copy and paste the piece of code I used on the collectionView with two cells per page and I changed the width. But when I am running the app, the collectionView doesn't scroll to the middle item. Do you know how to handle this case ?

Comment: @LouizaA - hmm... in the example code in my answer, I changed `let w = cvWidth * 0.5` to `let w = cvWidth` and I get the exact same results, but with only "one cell per page." So, not sure where you'd be running into trouble?

Comment: So, I found that I missed this line "myCollectionView.isPagingEnabled = false" and now the collectionView works as expected. Thanks again DonMag!